# Android location manager ignore minTime

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-location

I want to set up a location manager to report the location every time the phone moves 30 meters. I do not care about time. Is there a way to "ignore" the minTime parameter? It appears if I set this to zero it is reporting constantly which is draining my battery. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(long minTime, float minDistance, Criteria criteria, PendingIntent intent)
```

Just set the minDistace to 30 and a large minTime. If either param is 0, then location will constantly be updated.

Here's the [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

Comment: Ah, of course. So it looks like this is an OR condition? Phone moved x meters OR x seconds have elapsed? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is an OR condition. The docs say this: "The minDistance parameter can also be used to control the frequency of location updates. If it is greater than 0 then the location provider will only send your application an update when the location has changed by at least minDistance meters, **AND** at least minTime milliseconds have passed. However it is more difficult for location providers to save power using the minDistance parameter, so minTime should be the primary tool to conserving battery life."